# Ticket booking engine

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am going to build a flight ticket booking system.
My client has own planes. Under is basic concept of engine.
Admin will add flights.
Passengers, agents, franchises or admin will book the tickets.
They will be developed in PHP with MySQL.
On each seat book request, I want to ensure every time that system not allocating already booked seat or system not allowing book seats more then actual number of seats in a plane.

Comment: Use trigger - each time the booking is made the trigger will check if seat is already booked and if the booking. Or you make check if the seat is booked before and tell that it can not be booked - I mean you make update only if the seat is not booked. If you make update of 0 records then the error is send to the user that seat is already booked.

Comment: As @BogdanBogdanov says, you can do it with a trigger, but at least you need to have some structure info of your database in your question.

Comment: Google "open source flight booking engine" - I got [this](http://ocportal.com/site/news/view/chris_grahams_blog/an-online-booking-engine.htm) which might be a start for your project. There are others which you can explore. It's a lot of work building a booking engine - I worked for a company which did this sort of work. My **opinion** is that PostgreSQL would be a better choice of db server.

Comment: As @oNare siad you need to provide us with some script which shows your database structure. I just give you a general clue.

Comment: I have not database yet as i just starting project and want to learn how design best database.

Comment: Ok, @user3458349. In cas you don't have DB script - put an image of DB scheme. In that case you can receive better recommendations. The general rule is: IT DEPENDS, so we need more details to tell you which is better way in our oppinion.